# iPhone as a USB microphone for PC

Tags: microphone, pc

Is it possible to use my iPhone as a microphone for my Windows PC using only a USB connection?

I searched for solutions and found some that require a male to male 3.5mm audio jack, but I would like to know if I can use the USB connection as a microphone.